# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac {\sin \left( n! \right) }{n!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial, closed-form, trigonometric-series

Have you got any ideas on how to evaluate this serie ?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac {\sin \left( n! \right) }{n!}}$$

It's convergent and is about ${2.057545430}$, but I don't find any ways to get a closed form.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? Are you asking for numerical evaluation? Or are you asking for closed forms?

Comment: I was thinking about a closed form just like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac {\sin \left( n \right) }{n}}=\cfrac{1+\pi}{2}$ but with this factorial boost instead.

Comment: It seems incredibly unlikely a closed form exists.

Comment: Although not exactly what you want, one may actually get a closed form for $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n!}$: it is equal to $e^{\cos1}\sin\sin1$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Do you have a source for the value of that sum?

Comment: @csch2 it's a simple exercise.

Comment: @csch2 It's the imaginary part of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{n!}=e^{e^{i}}$

Comment: For the approximation I used a CAS software but WolframAlpha works as well :

[sum sin(n!)/n! , n=0 to 1000](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sin%28n%21%29%2Fn%21+%2C+n%3D0+to+1000)

Answer (score 2):

I am skeptical about a possible closed form but you can always represent the result as (for example)
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac {\sin \left( n! \right) }{n!}}\sim a \pi$$ where tha $a$ is a rational number.

For example $a=\frac{3470614198}{5299156903}$ would give a absolute relative error of $2.79 \times 10^{-18}$.

Interesting enougth is also the fact that the number can be *approximated* as the product of $\pi$ by the first positive root of
$$6074 x^4-6882 x^3+2117 x^2-7479 x+4806=0$$ which would give a absolute relative error of $1.36 \times 10^{-19}$.

**Edit**

For the solution of
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n!}$$ given by @WhatsUp in comments, consider
$$\Im\left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\left(e^i\right)^n}{n!}\right)=\Im\left(e^{e^i}\right)=\Im\left(e^{\cos(1)+i\sin(1)}\right)=e^{\cos (1)}\Im\left( \cos (\sin (1))+i \sin (\sin (1)) \right)$$